# How to encrypt all mails in a maildir / IMAP-Account with S/MIME or PGP?

Tags: email, encryption, pgp, smime

Hi,

I would like to encrypt all my existing mails at my IMAP Account.
If a hacker is entering my account, he would be unable to read any of my mails.

I have tried to get a tool, encrypting all mails in a local maildir,
but did not found a well solution.
Most solutions encrypt incomming or outgoing mails.

Still encrypted mails should be excluded.
Does anyone know a such a tool or a good java libary for working with mails including attachments?

- Encryption of all not encrypted mails in the dir / account.
- Decryption with default S/MIME or PGP tools is possible
- One Key is used: for example "Archive2017"

Thanks in Advance

Same idea like here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/238717/script-encrypting-mails-on-server-maildir-gpg

Comment: https://gitlab.com/mikecardwell/gpgit/tree/master

may work.

I will check this.

Comment: `apt-get install libmail-gnupg-perl`

Comment: `cat mail.eml | perl gpgit.pl user1234@domain.de >mail.gpg.eml`

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).